# Authentication request not working

Tags: symfony, authentication, request

i tried to set up authentication process, it works fine, when i use memory providers such as:

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:             
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                ryan:
                    password: $2a$12$LCY0MefVIEc3TYPHV9SNnuzOfyr2p/AXIGoQJEDs4am4JwhNz/jl
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                admin:
                    password: $2a$12$LCY0MefVIEc3TYPHV9SNnuzOfyr2p/AXIGoQJEDs4am4JwhNz/j2
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

When i try to use entity providers (in security.yml) such as:

```
security:    
    encoders:
         AppBundle\Model\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
         database_users:
          entity: { class: AppBundle\Model\Entity\User, property: username }

   firewalls:
         dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false

         default:
          anonymous: ~
          http_basic: ~
          form_login:
          login_path: /login
          check_path: /login_check

access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

following error shows: **Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.**

Comment: does User class implements UserInterface?

Comment: Yes, implements, I tried clear cache and update schema, but it does not work.

Comment: I have encountered this error as well and this was because my user role did not match the access_control role. In my case, this was a case mismatch (roles are case sensitive). I had Role_Admin in my DB and the acces_control was ROLE_ADMIN . Hope this will help someone in the future ^^